# Requesting assistance to clean a specific type of questions

Tags: discussion, clean-up

When you search for *[OOO000000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=OOO000000)*, you find 12 results relating to a backdoor script in PHP.

Questions about this specific backdoor still do come up every once and a while, and we always close them as Too Localized. Since these questions *do* seem to repeat themselves, Too Localized seems to have lost some of its merit.

Now I've found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700767/871050)**, which can be considered as some sort of reference question.

I request assistance in closing the other questions as duplicates of that, so that we can use it as a sink for all of this types of questions.

Comment: Better to close it as exact duplicated than too localized. I casted some votes.